# Encode plaintext Symfony 4

Tags: symfony4

I have two controllers SecurityController & UserController

```
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('security/index.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
public function register(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    // whatever *your* User object is
    $user = new App\Entity\User();
    $plainPassword = 'ryanpass';
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);

    $user->setPassword($encoded);
}
```

User controller

```
public function editUser(Request $request, User $user, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): Response
{   $plainPassword = 'ryanpass';
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $plainPassword);
    $user->setPassword($encoded);

    $form = $this->createForm(User1Type::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_edit', ['id' => $user->getId()]);
    }

    return $this->render('user/edit.html.twig', [
        'user' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

When i encode the plainpassword through the login register using the SecurityController all works fine and the HASH stored in the database match with the password.

But if I try to process this plaintext with a new string the HASH is being updated but not match with the supposed plain text.

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: btw you can fully review the code here: https://github.com/VGzsysadm/Inventory-app

Comment: Sorry, i was taking the wrong function. Must be : // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
        $form = $this->createForm(User1Type::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);